# I got a memory surge using goroutine for parral, eventually oom

Tags: go

I just started to learn go. I am trying to do a sum calculation in go. Code below

```
func test() {
    start := time.Now()
    ret := make(chan int)
    go foo(1, 100000, ret)
    ssum := <- ret
    elap := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(ssum)
    fmt.Printf("used time in milli is %d", elap)
}

func foo(start, end int, ret chan int) {
    if start > end {
        ret <- 0
        return
    }
    if end - start <= 10000 {
        sum := 0
        for i := start; i <=end; i++ {
            sum += i
        }
        ret <- sum
        return
    }
    mid := (end - start) / 2
    leftRet := make(chan int)
    go foo(start, mid, leftRet)
    leftNum := <- leftRet
    rightRet := make(chan int)
    go foo(mid+1, end, rightRet)
    rightNum := <- rightRet
    ret <- leftNum + rightNum
}
```

1. Does the code above do parrallel computing? Since goroutine are not mulitiple process, not even multiple threads. I am not sure if goroutine can be used to do parrell computing.
2. Why did I get memory surge and oom?

Comment: Since you've created the channel using `make(chan int)`, it created a channel of buffer size 0.  This means that every single send will block until another goroutine receives from the channel.  So, all I want to say that use of a channel of buffer size 0, is not appropriate for this scenario.

Comment: I would recommend you go through the official Go Tour if you are not familiar to the language: https://tour.golang.org

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Very intuitive. Gonna try tour.golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not doing anything in parallel. You create a goroutine, and immediately wait for its return value, where each goroutine performs a computation, writes the result to a channel and returns. So there is no parallelism there. You might get some concurrent execution if you move the channel reads to the line after all goroutine creation, so two goroutines can run.

Your program is not correct, and that's why it is not terminating. `mid` is not `(end-start)/2`, it is `(end+start)/2`. It is likely that it is falling into a case where `end-start` is larger than 10000 and `mid` is such that you end up running the same start and end values over and over again. Put a println statement after that mid computation to see what the start and end values are.

Comment: Very much thanks to you! I got it. You state yourself very clear. 

1.  I changed (end-start)/2 to (end+start)/2，problem solved.

2.  It indeed didn't do any anything in parallel as you said.  It costs more time than normal 'for'.

Obviously, I didn't understand channel very well, I decided to have go through tour.golang.

Comment: And the advice of moving the channel reads to the line after all goroutine creation works well! It Increased the speed by 5 times, making goroutine solution 2times faster than the normal 'for' solution ( end is 10000000000, gomaxprocs is 12)